# How to wrap the mention in a special span tag after selecting it? Like Facebook or Stackoverflow tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mention

Am using [ment.io](https://github.com/jeff-collins/ment.io) an AngularJS plugin that allows mentions to be used.

But I am unable to find out how to change the look and feel of the selected mention.

For e.g. in Stackoverflow
[image]

For e.g. in Facebook
[image]

Comment: Have you had a look @ https://github.com/alihaghighatkhah/angular-otobox - it seems to trigger what you want.

Comment: I couldn't find a good example using otobox. At least mentio comes with examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised the key is

1. I must have the directive below:

   ```
   .directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) { 

   return {
       restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
       require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           function read() {
               var html = element.html();
               // When we clear the content editable the browser 
               // leaves a <br> behind 
               // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
               if (attrs.stripBr && html === '<br>') {
                   html = '';
               }
               ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
           }


           if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

           // Specify how UI should be updated
           ngModel.$render = function() {
               if (ngModel.$viewValue !== element.html()) {
                   element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
               }
           };

           // Listen for change events to enable binding
           element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
               scope.$apply(read);
           });
           read(); // initialize
       }
   };

   }])
   ```
2. I need to mark the div that will look like the textarea or input text as contenteditable
3. for whatever weird span I want to do, I need to change this function accordingly

   ```
   $scope.getPeopleText = function(item) {
       // note item.label is sent when the typedText wasn't found
       return '<span class="menu-highlighted">' + (item.name || item.label) + '</span>';
   };
   ```